# How to get only values from kafka sources to spark?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting logs from kafka sources, and put it into spark.
Format of logs which are saved in my hadoop_path looks like this
`{"value":"{\"Name\":\"Amy\",\"Age\":\"22\"}"}`
`{"value":"{\"Name\":\"Jin\",\"Age\":\"26\"}"}`

But, I want to make this like
`{\"Name\":\"Amy\",\"Age\":\"22\"}`
`{\"Name\":\"Jin\",\"Age\":\"26\"}`

Any kind of solution will be great. (Using pure Java code, Spark SQL, or Kafka)

```
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local")
                .appName("MYApp").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Kafka_source)
                .option("subscribe", Kafka_topic)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .option("failOnDataLoss",false)
                .load();
        Dataset<Row> dg = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)");
        StreamingQuery queryone = dg.writeStream()
                .format("json")
                .outputMode("append")
                .option("checkpointLocation",Hadoop_path)
                .option("path",Hadoop_path)
                .start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have done it with from_json fucntion!!

```
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local")
                .appName("MYApp").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Kafka_source)
                .option("subscribe", Kafka_topic)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .option("failOnDataLoss",false)
                .load();
        Dataset<Row> dg = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)");
        Dataset<Row> dz = dg.select(
                        from_json(dg.col("value"), DataTypes.createStructType(
                        new StructField[] {
                                DataTypes.createStructField("Name", StringType,true)
                        })).getField("Name").alias("Name")
                        ,from_json(dg.col("value"), DataTypes.createStructType(
                        new StructField[] {
                                DataTypes.createStructField("Age", IntegerType,true)
                        })).getField("Age").alias("Age")
        StreamingQuery queryone = dg.writeStream()
                .format("json")
                .outputMode("append")
                .option("checkpointLocation",Hadoop_path)
                .option("path",Hadoop_path)
                .start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
Dataframe<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Kafka_source)
                .option("subscribe", Kafka_topic)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .option("failOnDataLoss",false)
                .load();
df.printSchema();
StreamingQuery queryone = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
            .writeStream()
            .format("json")
            .outputMode("append")
            .option("checkpointLocation",Hadoop_path)
            .option("path",Hadoop_path)
            .start();
```

Make sure, schema contains `value` as column.

Comment: First of all, it returns same result as mine. It means, json file in Hadoop_path includes "{"value":" part too. Moreover, i'm not sure what is difference between your code and my code, because my code also uses `dg=df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")` too. Can I ask what is your opinion about why I can't get only values, not including "{"value":" part?

Comment: Did you check the schema for your df or ds? My guess is either your data is not in  proper json format?

Comment: Kafka source throws schema with 7 dimension which include key, value, timestamp, etc. And value of "value" is obviously json. But when I use `printschema`, it only shows "value" : [something].

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected results using Spark as below:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local")
                .appName("MYApp").getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Kafka_source)
                .option("subscribe", Kafka_topic)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .option("failOnDataLoss",false)
                .load();

Dataset<Row> dg = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
        .withColumn("Name", functions.json_tuple(functions.col("value"),"Name"))
        .withColumn("Age", functions.json_tuple(functions.col("value"),"Age"));

StreamingQuery queryone = dg.writeStream()
                .format("json")
                .outputMode("append")
                .option("checkpointLocation",Hadoop_path)
                .option("path",Hadoop_path)
                .start();
```

Basically, you have to create separate columns for each of the fields inside the json string in value column.